# Locking rows in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, concurrency, transactions

I'm trying to implement [this awsome solution about row locking](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167283/148450) in order to assert atomic insertions conditioned by row counts in Django while using PostgreSQL as DB backend. I've tested the solution in the PostgresSQL shell like this:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM teams WHERE id = 3 FOR NO KEY UPDATE;
-- other stuff
COMMIT;
```

and it worked as a charm: while executing the same code in another shell, it got blocked (exactly what I'm looking for) till I run `COMMIT;` in my first shell.

However, I can't get it working in Django. I've tried differentet approaches, like:

1- Executing the whole algorith as raw SQL:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
   cursor.execute("BEGIN;")
   cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM app_team WHERE id = 1 FOR NO KEY UPDATE;")
   #other stuff
   cursor.execute("COMMIT;")
```

2- Wrapping that with a `with transaction.atomic():` statement instead of the raw `BEGIN;` and `COMMIT;` queries

3- Using the default Django's `select_for_update`:

```
with transaction.atomic():    
    team = Team.objects.select_for_update().get(id=1)
```

Which is the best way to implement such a mechanism in Django?

Comment: Method 3 should work fine. You'll have to provide more details on what isn't working, as well as the actual code that you're trying to run.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry I'm just testing that approach in the Django shell. What I'm doing is selecting for update one specific row within a transaction.atomic() block and printing the queryset. I think that it isn't working because I run that code in two shells: I select for update in both of them  and then print the queryset only in the shell that selected for update by last. I think that it doesn't work because it prints the result before I end the transaction of the first one. I expected the second shell to be blocked, as long it was the second to adquiere the lock till the first one ended.

Comment: `select_for_update()` definitely works as documented, so there's probably something wrong with your test procedure. You'll have to update the question with your exact test code if you want help with that.